# How do I make an automated build use same output folders as a manual build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

### Background

Currently I have many C# projects in many TFS team projects.

Several C# projects reference C# projects in different team projects. I do this by referencing the output dll in the Bin/Release folder of the other C# project.

As long as we checkout & build the solutions in the team projects in the correct order everything works fine on all dev's machines.

We're moving to Visual Studio Online and I'm playing around with automated builds.

### Problem

The problem I'm having is that it can't find the dlls to reference, even after the project that would output them (to \Bin\Release) has ran.

I've disabled parallel builds (to ensure the referenced projects get built first) and this seems to be the case based on the build logs. The issue is that the projects that depend on these can't find the dlls and as a result I get "the type or namespace could not be found" errors everywhere.

What's the easiest way of resolving this?

---

Note that I've read several posts/tutorials etc. about this but all seem to involve changing the source control structure, or fiddling about with workspaces etc. I want something where I can keep the simple workspace mapping on the dev's machines where we map "$\" to "C:\TFS\". I don't want to have to remember to periodically merge in changes from a shared library, or maintain lots of folder mappings within a workspace (on dev machines).

Comment: Do you use the cloud hosted build or on-premises build server?

Comment: Cloud based; Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 0):

Open your process template xaml (usually `DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml` or `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` with XML editor, not the designer). Look for `mtbwa:MSBuild` on `Run MSBuild for Project` activity. Remove the `OutDir` attribute, save and check-in. This will force MSBuild to use the default OutDir for each project.